# Unrecognized Selector when Passing Parameter - UIButton in TableView Cell | Swift iOS

Tags: ios, uitableview, uibutton

I've had this issue before but it usually due to not having a button hooked up in Storyboard or not passing a parameter when the function is expecting one, like most of the existing questions on here seem to suggest. This time however it is neither of those things.

I am creating a button in my TableView Cell by using this code in the `CellForRowAt` method:

```
let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
button.addTarget(self, action: Selector(("showPeople:")), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
button.tag = indexPath.row
cell.addSubview(button)
```

and I have declared the `showPeople` method like so:

```
func showPeople(sender: UIButton) {
    print("pressed")
}
```

When the button is pressed the program crashed with the following message:

```
showPeople: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

But when I declare the method like so (remove the parameter):

```
func showPeople() {
    print("pressed")
}
```

and change the selector to `Selector(("showPeople"))` it works fine which I guess means there is an issue with the way I'm passing the parameter. Why would this be happening? The function is expecting a parameter so the `:` is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing `sender` part in your selector.

Try this instead:

```
button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.showPeople(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: That's because in Swift 2 first parameter name was not used for external signature. So to call the same `showPeople(sender: UIButton)` method in swift 2 you were doing `showPeople(button)` and in in Swift 3 you have to call showPeople(sender: button).

Comment: And to omit parameter name you have to add underscore in method implementation, like this: func showPeople(_ sender: UIButton)